# Automation IE - VBA problems, can't assign a value to a object in HTML

Tags: html, vba, automation

I'm building a code to automate a routine in VBA to IE in my intranet server.
When i try to assign a value to a object in HTML, vba returns error, and i dont know what i need to do.

Html code line of my intranet server.

the option "value" only appears when i input manualy a value:

```
INPUT onkeypress=soNumero() class=WidthFull maxLength=9 value=20000 name=numseqrs
```

when i open the blank html, this option doesnt appears..

```
INPUT onkeypress=soNumero() class=WidthFull maxLength=9 name=numseqrs
```

my sub routine : (this take any opened IE window and control)

```
Sub test()

Dim Shell_Application As Object
Dim Open_Window As Object
Dim IE As Object
Dim ca As Integer
Dim ele As Object



Set Shell_Application = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

For Each Open_Window In Shell_Application.Windows
If TypeName(Open_Window.document) = "HTMLDocument" Then

Set IE = Open_Window
Exit For
End If
Next

If IE Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "não achei"
    Else
    MsgBox "achei"

IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("numseqrs").value = "12345"

Set IE = Nothing
Set Shell_Application = Nothing


End Sub
```

When i try to assign a value to `"numseqrs"` (12345), vba returns error *Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)*.

Comment: Your class name is `WidthFull` I belive,  `getElementsByName` maybe the one for you?  Also, `getElementsbyClassName` returns a collection, so maybe `IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("numseqrs")(0).value `

Comment: both doesnt :/, returns the same error

Comment: Set `IE.document.getElementsbyClassName("numseqrs")` to just an `object` then see if it contains anything.   Also, Is it the right window?  You're taking a window with type `htmldocument`, the first one it finds and where's your `End If` for the 2nd if block?